# Cleanest way to convert GMT timestamp(6) to system date in Oracle

Tags: oracle

The underlying tables of both the traditional auditing (`SYS.AUD$`) and unified auditing (`AUDSYS.AUD$UNIFIED`) store their timestamps as a `TIMESTAMP(6)` column (no time zone) and it's always in GMT/UTC. **I need to convert this to *system time*** (in `DATE` datatype) so it lines up with most other dictionary dates (like `v$session.logon_time`). There's plenty of discussion on converting to *local* time, but I need *system* time. One would think there'd be something like `[timestamp] AT SYSTEM` akin to `[timestamp] AT LOCAL`, but there's not.

I've never fully cleared my mind of the fogginess around timezones, so I find it always a bit of a trial-and-error struggle every time. The following conversion works, but doesn't seem very elegant:

From `audsys.aud$unified.event_timestamp` to system date:

```
var_system_date := CAST(event_timestamp AS date)-(CAST(SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS date)-SYSDATE)
```

From system date back to `audsys.aud$unified.event_timestamp` (except for the fractional seconds, which I don't need):

```
event_timestamp = CAST(var_system_date + (CAST(SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS date)-SYSDATE) AS timestamp))
```

I'm essentially using date subtraction to get the fractional difference in days between system time and GMT, then either adding or subtracting that offset to convert between the two in my queries. I can think of a few other ways but they are all just as kludgy or worse. Surely there's a cleaner, more elegant way that I'm overlooking?

Comment: What do you mean by "system time"?

Comment: The database time returned by SYSDATE or SYSTIMESTAMP and found in most dictionary dates. I'm trying to conform the audit event timestamps to the database's system time rather than using GMT or session local.

Answer (score 2):

Don't play around with adding/subtraction time values.

`SYSDATE` returns the current `DATE` in the time zone of database server's operating system, so I assume you are looking for this.

You can interrogate the time zone of database server's operating system with `TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'tzr')`

Try this one:

```
CAST(
   FROM_TZ(event_timestamp , 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'tzr')
   AS DATE)
```

Comment: That's it, I knew there had to be a cleaner way. I thought I tried this earlier but I guess I must have messed it up somehow and assumed `AT TIME ZONE` required a literal. It'd still be nice to not have to steal the timezone from SYSTIMESTAMP since it's going to return the current time when that isn't needed, but it's cleaner than doing subtraction.

Comment: The problem is, you cannot query the time zone of database server's operating system directly (at least I am not aware of any method), thus you must derive it from `SYSTIMESTAMP`